# How hash code is generated for StringBuffer object in java?

Tags: java, string, hashcode, stringbuffer

I am studying `String` in java and while studying I came to know that hash code is generated for every string.

I want to know how hash code is generated in the case of `StringBuffer`.

Comment: A question like this is something you should consider reading [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) for rather than asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `StringBuffer` class does not override the `hashCode()` method inherited from `Object` class, whenever the `hashCode` is invoked on a `StringBuffer` instance the `Object` class's implementation of `hashCode` is used.

This is because the `StringBuffer` is a mutable object unlike the `String` you can easily modify the state of the `StringBuffer` object after its creation. This makes it unsuitable for use in any "hash" based data structures like a `HashMap` as the it will be inconsistent.

The `hashCode` method of the `Object` class is a native method which is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer as the hash code value or may not as it depends on the internal implementation of the JVM, but in the immutable `String` class the `hashCode` is overriden and implemented using the content of the `String` object to make it consistent for use in hash data structures.

Just as simple experiment you can run the snippet to check this theory:

```
StringBuffer s1 = new StringBuffer("foo");
StringBuffer s2 = new StringBuffer("foo");

System.out.println(s1.hashCode() == s2.hashCode());
System.out.println(s1.toString().hashCode() == s2.toString().hashCode());
```

This will output `false` and `true`. This is because the `String` instance is actually using the state of the object to calculate the hash code, so it is same for both `s1.toString()` and `s2.toString()`.

Comment: @JasmeetSingh you're welcome.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is factually incorrect.  In modern JVMs, the machine address is typically NOT used to generate the identity hashcode.  See the linked Q&A.

Comment: @StephenC I used the reference form the Java docs, which it seems does not go into the implementation technique, thanks for the link I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[`StringBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) extends [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html) class directly and it does not override `hashCode` from `Object` class. So the implementation of `StringBuffer::hashCode` is the same as for [`Object::hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()).